# How can I show colorAxis color in Highcharts legend as series color?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to show color coded pie chart using Highcharts. In the legend each series should have a color based on `minColor` and `maxColor`.

On first render this doesn't work (the legend has default colors like blue, black and green) and only after the `redraw()` event correct colors appear in the legend.

I'd like to avoid calling `redraw()` method manually as I have very many charts that get their data dynamically from external APIs, so doing it manually would increase my code complexity a bit too much.

Any ideas or suggestions?

You can see working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/p0cf392j/
(Resize your browser window to trigger the `redraw()` event and see the series colors change in the legend)

Comment: In case the jsfiddle link has correct colors, click the "Run" button to reset the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem is a Highcharts bug, which I already reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12710

As a workaround, you can overwrite the `translateColors` method:

```
(function(H) {
    H.Series.prototype.translateColors = function() {
        var series = this,
            points = this.data.length ? this.data : this.points,
            nullColor = this.options.nullColor,
            colorAxis = this.colorAxis,
            colorKey = this.colorKey;

        points.forEach(function(point) {
            var value = point[colorKey],
                color;

            color = point.options.color ||
                (
                    point.isNull ?
                    nullColor :
                    (colorAxis && typeof value !== 'undefined') ?
                    colorAxis.toColor(value, point) :
                    point.color || series.color
                );

            if (color && point.color !== color) {
                point.color = color;

                if (series.options.legendType === 'point') {
                    series.chart.legend.colorizeItem(point, point.visible);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ht0nwvxj/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts